# Is there a "unification" explanation of why the mixed gauge-gravitational anomaly cancels in the standard model?

Tags: standard-model, quantum-gravity, quantum-anomalies, unified-theories

Quoting the Review of Particle Physics ([93.2.3](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2022/reviews/rpp2022-rev-guts.pdf)):

> all representations of SO(10) are anomaly free in four dimensions... the absence of anomalies in ... a SM generation can be viewed as deriving from this feature.

Does the cancellation of the mixed anomaly have a similarly straightforward derivation, in any unified theory?